# std::chrono: Set clock's epoch to 1/1/0000

Tags: c++, c++11, epoch, c++-chrono

Is it possible to manually set the epoch date/time to the January 1, 0000, so I might use the std::chrono::time_point::time_since_epoch to calculate the difference between a given date and January 1, 0000?

I tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    std::tm epochStart = {};
    epochStart.tm_sec = 0;
    epochStart.tm_min = 0;
    epochStart.tm_hour = 0;
    epochStart.tm_mday = 0;
    epochStart.tm_mon = 0;
    epochStart.tm_year = -1900;
    epochStart.tm_wday = 0;
    epochStart.tm_yday = 0;
    epochStart.tm_isdst = -1;

    std::time_t base = std::mktime(&epochStart);

    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point baseTp=
        std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(base);
    std::time_t btp = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(baseTp);
    std::cout << "time: " << std::ctime(&btp);

}
```

but this gives me

```
time: Thu Jan  1 00:59:59 1970
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would avoid `std::time_t` altogether.  Using `days_from_civil` from [chrono-Compatible Low-Level Date Algorithms](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html), you can immediately compute any difference between `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`, and *any* date in the [proleptic Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar)<sup>1</sup>.

In addition to `days_from_civil` which takes a year/month/day triple and converts it into a count of days before/since 1970-01-01 (a chrono-compatible epoch), it is also convenient to create a custom `chrono::duration` to represent 24 hours:

```
typedef std::chrono::duration
        <
            int,
            std::ratio_multiply<std::ratio<24>, std::chrono::hours::period>
        > days;
```

Now you can create any epoch you want with just:

```
constexpr days epoch = days(days_from_civil(0, 1, 1));  // 0000-01-01
```

In C++1y this is even a compile-time computation!

And you can subtract this `std::chrono::duration` from *any* other `std::chrono::duration`:

```
auto delta = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch() - epoch;
```

`delta` is now a `std::chrono::duration` representing the amount of time between now, and 0000-01-01.  You can then print that out however you want, or otherwise manipulate it.  For example here is an entire working demo:

```
#include "../date_performance/date_algorithms"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

typedef std::chrono::duration
        <
            int,
            std::ratio_multiply<std::ratio<24>, std::chrono::hours::period>
        > days;

int
main()
{
    constexpr days epoch = days(days_from_civil(0, 1, 1));
    auto delta = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch() - epoch;
    days d = std::chrono::duration_cast<days>(delta);
    std::cout << "It has been " << d.count() << " days, ";
    delta -= d;
    auto h = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(delta);
    std::cout << h.count() << " hours, ";
    delta -= h;
    auto m = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(delta);
    std::cout << m.count() << " minutes, ";
    delta -= m;
    auto s = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(delta);
    std::cout << s.count() << " seconds ";
    std::cout << " since 0000-01-01\n";
}
```

Which for me output:

```
It has been 735602 days, 19 hours, 14 minutes, 32 seconds  since 0000-01-01
```

**A word of warning about overflow:**

The `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point::duration` is not guaranteed to have a range large enough to do this.  It turns out that on my system it does.  It is microseconds in a signed long long which will span +/- 292,000 years.  If you need to avoid an overflow problem, you could truncate your `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point::duration` to courser units (e.g. seconds or days) to extend the range prior to subtracting 0000-01-01.

**I got to thinking**

And that usually leads to a disaster.  However in this case I decided I should add to this post anyway.  This:

```
constexpr days epoch = days(days_from_civil(0, 1, 1));
```

has type `days`, which is a `duration`.  But it really isn't a `duration`.  It is a point in time.  It is a date.  It is a `time_point` with a coarse precision.  By introducing a new typedef, the code in this post can be cleaned up just a little bit more:

```
typedef std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, days> date_point;
```

Now instead of writing:

```
constexpr days epoch = days(days_from_civil(0, 1, 1));
```

One can write:

```
constexpr date_point epoch{days(days_from_civil(0, 1, 1))};
```

But even more importantly, instead of:

```
auto delta = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch() - epoch;
```

we can now write:

```
auto delta = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - epoch;
```

This `delta` still has exactly the same type and value as it did previously, and everything else in the demo still proceeds as exactly as it did before.

This is both a small change, and a big change.  By treating `epoch` as a `time_point` instead of a `duration`, the algebra of `time_point`'s and `duration`'s works for us, both simplifying *and* type-checking our expressions to help us write cleaner code with fewer mistakes.

For example one can add two `duration`'s together.  But it doesn't make any sense at all to:

```
epoch + epoch
```

By using `time_point` instead of `duration` for the type of `epoch`, the compiler catches such non-sensical expressions at compile time.

<sup>1</sup>The [proleptic Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar) has a year 0.  In the year 0 it is 2 days behind the Julian calendar.  Using a year 0 is also consistent with ISO 8601.  As long as all parties involved know what calendar you are using, then everything is fine.  Conversion between non-positive years and "BC years" is trivial if desired.

Comment: +1 for **chrono-Compatible Low-Level Date Algorithms**. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, the code you've given (minus a small fix, `tm_mday` starts with `1`) yields:

```
Sat Jan  1 00:00:00 0
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbdee17c11b37dda)

The real problem is: Are you on 32-bit or 64-bit? With a 32-bit system, `time_t` is also only 32 bits and you are limited to 1970 +/- 68 years.

On a 64-bit system, the limits are given by `std::mktime` and `std::strftime`, in my own code I have unit test for those strings and the corresponding values:

```
"-2147481748-01-01 00:00:00" maps to -67768040609740800
"2147483647-12-31 23:59:59" maps to 67767976233532799
```

I should probably also mention that there are systems where the above does not work because the underlying OS functions are buggy. For the record: I'm on Linux.

Comment: I'm working on MacOS X 10.9.1 (Mavericks) - my executable is 64-bit:

    file src/demo
    src/demo: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

And: your code still gives me Thu Jan  1 00:59:59 1970 ;-(, whereas the live example is giving Sat Jan  1 00:00:00 0.

Comment: @JohannHorvat That might be your problem, I can't confirm it right now but I remember that MacOS had some problems in this area. In case you are interested: The correct value for `0-01-01 00:00:00` is `-62167219200` (all values are UTC).

Answer (score 1):

No. `mktime` and friends are based on UNIX time, which starts on 1st January 1970.

There is in fact no such thing as 0th January, 0000, so it seems likely that you would be better off finding another way to solve whatever is your *actual* problem.

Comment: `0` is `1st January 1970`, but the values can be negative.

Comment: @DanielFrey: That's for permitting intervals between two dates, not for going back in time to arbitrary made-up dates. (Hint: 1BC led into 1AD)